# i want keep those rows which has null data output using panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a quick question on reading excel file using Pandas. The excel file which I have has the format:

```
Num  Date     Value1   Value2   Value3 
1   7/29/11    1        2        3       
2   7/22/11    NA       3        1       
3   7/15/11    5        NA       NA  
4   7/6/11    -1        0        2
```

I would like to read this excel file using pandas. However, I need to keep the rows which have either of the column entries as NA (in this case I need to skip rows 1 and 4).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove row with null value from pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548721/remove-row-with-null-value-from-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```