# Dropping Nulls and Slicing from Pivoted Table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, slice

I'm having trouble slicing my pivoted data frame so that I get results above a certain threshold. I'm trying to filter out results that fall below a minimum value. My data frame looks like so:

```
                                                                                    Qty                             
Index   Store_Nbr   201712  201801  201802  201803  201804  201805  201806  201807  201808
0               1      356     275     293     256     313     421     493     291     385
1               2      147     316     343     416     361     483     438     136     461
2               3      266     370     162     346     451     414     296     478     295
3               4      322     179     353     241     370     247     423     391     194
4               5      249     389     480     450     102     482     137     251     153
...            ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
30             30        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
31             31        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
32             32        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
33             33      392     311     151     488     135     239     212     104     122
34             34        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      -1
```

After using `godzilla = godzilla[godzilla['Qty'] > 150]` I get the below data frame where it has converted all of the zero to nulls and hasn't filtered out anything.

```
                                                                                     Qty                                
Index   Store_Nbr   201712   201801  201802  201803  201804  201805  201806  201807  201808
0             NaN      NaN      275     293     256     313     421     493     291     385
1             NaN      147      316     343     416     361     483     438     136     461
2             NaN      266      370     162     346     451     414     296     478     295
3             NaN      NaN      179     353     241     370     247     423     391     194
4             NaN      389      480     450     102     482     137     251     153     153
...           ...     ...       ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
30            NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
31            NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
32            NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
33            NaN      NaN      311     151     488     135     239     212     104     122
34            NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I've tried doing `godzilla.dropna(axis = 0, inplace = True, how = 'any')` which returns an empty dataframe and  `godzilla = godzilla.dropna( subset = godzilla['Qty'])` which returns a KeyError: 'Qty'. I'm baffled that it converted zeroes in nulls and why the slice isn't working. Any words of wisdom when trying to filter/slice pivoted data?

Note** That I have more than Qty being pivoted in the data frame.

Comment: what do you want to do when a row has not all columns as null?

Comment: If a row has even one null value I want to exclude it.

Comment: I think an idea of the whole pivot including other things than "Qty" would be helpful - in fact, try to make a dummy dataframe and apply solutions to it, often finds the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Sorry for the delay. Appreciate the answers you all put forward. The mistake was completely on my part. Earlier in the code I had used `.drop_index()` because I didn't realize at the time I could manipulate the index using `.index`. After I corrected the code then I had no problems setting parameters using `godzilla = godzilla[godzilla['Qty'] > 150].dropna()`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you replace every value lower than 150 with None.
Than you should filter out row with at least 1 None value as described in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548721/)

This should do the trick:

```
# replaces every value of the DataFrame lower than 150 with None
godzilla = pd.DataFrame([
    [x if not isinstance(x, (int, float)) or x >= 150 else None for x in j
] for j in godzilla.as_matrix()])

# replaces every value of the Column "Qty" lower than 150 with None
df["Qty"] = [x if not isinstance(x, (int, float)) or x >= 20 else None for x in df["Qty"]

#dropna will drop all rows with at least 1 null value
df = df.dropna(how='any',axis=0)
```

Comment: This does not work. If I could get the slice to work in the first place, that would be optimal.

Comment: Getting this back 'TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable'

Comment: What did you do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You are working with a hierarchical structure, multiindex. That's why the columns are not being dropped, but replaced with `NaN`. If there are no other indexes other than `Qty` you can use:

```
godzilla.columns = godzilla.columns.droplevel()
```

And then follow it with the `dropna()`:

```
godzilla = godzilla.dropna(how='any',axis=0)
```

Comment: I got an empty data frame with no values.

@Celius, what is the proper way to slice the hierarchical  dataframe so that I can filter out the 0's to begin with?

Comment: They work as tuples, so your index is ('Qty','Store_Nbr'),('Qty','201712'),('Qty','201801') and so on...

Comment: It makes sense because all rows in `Store_Nbr` are null, this is, tey don't fulfill the condition. You should consider dropping it before using the `dropna(how='any',axis=0')`