# Getting ValueError while using fit_transform method from sklearn

Tags: pandas, encoding, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, feature-scaling

## I have a data-set(breast-cancer detection) with all numerical data and have divided the data-set into X(containing all features) and y(output class).After splitting the data into training and test sets I am facing an issue on applying feature scaling.On applying feature scaling I am getting an Value-Error: could not convert string to float: '?'.Although I have already replaced '?' with -9999 previously.

```
X=df.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=df.iloc[:,-1].values
```

#Now splitting data into training and test data.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)
```

#Replacing '?' with -9999.

```
df=df.replace('?',-9999)
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```

#Applying label encoding on y.

```
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train[:, 1:] = sc.fit_transform(X_train[:, 1:])
X_test[:, 1:] = sc.transform(X_test[:, 1:])
```

#After this I am getting value error.So how can I ensure that the '?' are not remaining in the data or is there any categorical encoding to be done?

Comment: check with smaller data, if it runs or not. then go for larger data and do check for null pointers.

Comment: @DurgeshKumar I have checked with small data and also searched for nan values throughout the data set using df.isnull().sum().But there are no missing data or '?' values in the data.Please help if there is some other way out.

Comment: on small data is it running?

Comment: @DurgeshKumar Yes it is running on small data.

Comment: ok then just skip the null values line.
`# drop all rows with any NaN and NaT values
df1 = df.dropna()
print(df1)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548721/remove-row-with-null-value-from-pandas-data-frame/44548976 follow this link

Comment: @DurgeshKumar Thank you for the help.The problem is solved by the advise and the link is of great help.